# Bluetooth and Wifi together on my Acer TravelMate 8572

Tags: bluetooth, wireless-networking, acer-travelmate

It seems the TravelMate 8572 only has one radio module, which I have to switch between Bluetooth, 3G, and Wifi. Is this so, or have I set something up wrong, or is there something I must still set up? Not having Wifi and 3G together is not really a problem, but I find it very inconvenient to not have Bluetooth while I'm on a Wifi or a 3G connection. I'm thinking of buying a USB Bluetooth adapter if I have to, but I could really use some advice on this situation.

Comment: In case someone still reads this... I have the same problem on Acer Travelmate. It seems like wifi and bluetooth really are in conflict. Maybe someone could solve bt/wifi problem using
`modprobe b43 -v btcoex=1`